# MariaDB ALTER TABLE: ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 11 "Resource temporarily unavailable" from storage engine InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, nfs

A couple of times so far, I got an error when issuing ALTER TABLE. However, after ~15 minutes the same command works fine.

```
MariaDB [mydatabase]> ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD COLUMN `fieldname` varchar(255) DEFAULT "" NOT NULL;
ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 11 "Resource temporarily unavailable" from storage engine InnoDB
MariaDB [mydatabase]>
```

**Where can I find information that helps finding out the root cause of this problem?**  MariaDB probably contains some status variables somewhere that can help giving a hint. I'm browsing the postings but no success so far.

The database is usage is very low, with only 1 user and few queries.

I'm using MariaDB 10.2.5, on Ubuntu 14LTS. MariaDB runs as a regular user (non root/mysql), and the database files are located in an NFS share.

Comment: Sounds like a timeout.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';  Or out-of-disk -- `ALTER ` usually needs to copy the entire table over.

Comment: Happened again. This time , I attempted to restart the database and got a failure:

Comment: Happened again. I restarted the DB but it failed to come back. In /var/log/syslog:  **[ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 116** , **[ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 116 means 'Stale file handle'**, **[ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace.**, **[ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Cannot open a file**, ** [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.**, **[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.**, **[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.**, **[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB**.

Comment: Tried again after  ~10 minutes and MariaDB restarted without the InnoDB error I've posted in my previous comment.

Comment: What is "NGF"?.

Comment: Sorry, a typo. I meant NFS. 
 
There is plenty of free space, 20GB available, and all database files are <5Mb. Wondering if perhaps some default timeout from MariaDB is too short when innodb files are in an NFS share.

Comment: There may be some low level timers that need adjusting, since NFS is slower than attached disks.  Research it from that point of view, perhaps in a different forum.

Comment: Got another weird error today, while trying to CREATE TABLE with Django migrate:  **django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, 'Can\'t create table `<db_name>`.`<table_name>` (errno: 168 "Unknown (generic) error from engine")')**.  I've moved the database files out of NFS to the local drive to see if it gets reproduced.

Comment: I haven't seen any  issues after moving the data files from MariaDB to the local drive (MariaDB is running on an ESXI Virtual Machine, the local drive is inside the same VM). My current assumption is that there is some issue on the NFS infrastructure or timings. Perhaps it can be fixed by adjusting MariaDB timers as I was suggested before.